# Lenovo's disable touchpad button not working

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys

So I have a Lenovo u310 with Ubuntu 13.10 on it and whenever I try to disable my touchpad with the special button on my F6 key, it does nothing.

All the other special keys work, like plane mode and refresh page but only the touchpad button is not working.

What might be wrong with it?

Comment: What does `xev -event keyboard` have to say when you press the key?

Comment: It shows absolutly nothing. Every other key shows something but that one does not.

Comment: But it does show when I hold the Fn key pressed and press F6,  then it works, but as just a F6 key.

Comment: Try just `xev`. Does anything show up then?

Comment: Still nothing. Seems to be the only F key that does nothing when you just press on it. But with Fn + F6 it works, ofcourse not in the way that I want.

Comment: same issue on Asus with 14.04 http://askubuntu.com/questions/544910/disable-touchpad-via-fn-key-asus-laptop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not work for me too(Ubuntu 13.10 Sony Vaio).

But I use following command(with shortcut key)

First determine the device id

```
xinput list
```

Then disable it, (this command as shortcut key action)

```
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Replace 15 with your device id.

SOURCE : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: So you basicly make a shortcut key that executes that command? But how can you make it so that when you click the same button again, it will reverse it=?   And are you using 13.10 ubuntu? Cause on that version the custom keyboard shortcuts options seems to be bugged.

Comment: Yh i m using, 13.10 GnomeUbuntu, and works nice for me.

Comment: I m using 2 keys, 1 to enable and 2nd to disable it.

Comment: With my x240 this disables the mouse buttons, too.

Comment: @guettli IMO Mouse buttons are part of Mouse Pad, so they will be disabled.

Comment: "xinput disable 15" also works (xinput 1.6.1)

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question about non working key, but it will help in case you want to use another key instead.

- **Another way using Gnome Settings**, Which I think it's better and simple as it will well integrated with desktop (Indicators...), the toggle script:

  ```
  if [ `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled` == "true" ]; then gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false ; else gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true ; fi
  ```

  Query status:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled
  ```

  Disable:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
  ```

  Enable:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true
  ```
- **Using `xinput`**:

  ```
  if [ `xinput list-props 12 | awk '/Device Enabled/ { print $4 }'` -eq 1 ]; then xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0 ; else xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1 ; fi
  ```

  `12` is the `id` you got from `xinput list`, but there a drawback here using predefined `id`. For example, If a new USB mouse attached/unplugged before boot, touchpad could get deferent `id`. (It happens to me with USB mouse, my touch pad damaged)
- **Using `xinput` and device name instead of `id`**:

  ```
  export touchpad_id=`xinput list | awk 'gsub(".*AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad[ \t]*id=*","") { print $1 }'` ; if [ `xinput list-props $touchpad_id | awk '/Device Enabled/ { print $4 }'` -eq 1 ]; then xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 0 ; else xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 1 ; fi
  ```

  My touchpad name is `AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad` got it from `xinput list`, replace it with your device name.

  Get device id by name `AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad` and store it in `touchpad_id`:

  ```
  export touchpad_id=`xinput list | awk 'gsub(".*AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad[ \t]*id=*","") { print $1 }'`
  ```

  Query status:

  ```
  xinput list-props $touchpad_id | awk '/Device Enabled/ { print $4 }'
  ```

  Disable:

  ```
  xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 0
  ```

  Enable:

  ```
  xinput set-prop $touchpad_id "Device Enabled" 1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Special touchpad key doesn't work on my Lenovo Ideapad 320 either (Ubuntu 16.04).
I installed [Touchpad Indicator](https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator) and configured it to turn off touchpad automatically when mouse is plugged in. The app started doing its job after I changed switch method to Xinput in its settings.

Answer (score -1):

I think this site will answer your question.
I do not own any lenovo to answer it
SITE
http://mydevelopedworld.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/how-to-configure-new-lenovo-x240-touchpad-on-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: No, the OP is having problems with the function keys not the touchpad itself. Also, posting just a link as an answer is generally frowned upon.