# Disable Touchpad via FN key (Asus Laptop)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad, function-keys

Most of my function (<kbd>Fn</kbd>) keys I care about work on my Asus G73 (like Volumne up/down, mute, Brightness up/down, Keyboard light up/down, Open Calculator) but the **<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>** to disable / enable touch pad does not work.

Info

```
product: G73Jh
vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
```

when I ran acpi_listen and for Vol up, down I get

```
hotkey ATK0100:00 00000030 00000003
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
hotkey ATK0100:00 00000031 00000001
button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
```

For the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

```
hotkey ATK0100:00 0000006b 00000004
```

I know that I can disable / enable touch-pad  in the GUI and terminal but would like to get the FN key working. 
Hope there is an easier way than this: [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Or should I follow this from 2009? (does it still work for 14.04? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopSpecialKeys

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Ubuntu. It stopped working for me too (Asus K52JC). In [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/412460/99330) second answer suggests different ways to patch this.

Comment: tried `xev -event keyboard`  and `xev` but on FN+F9 nothing, other key display something in the terminal.

Comment: Same issue here on an Asus n56vz.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I use with an XFCE-handled keyboard shortcut on my ASUS laptop because the touchpad hotkey is the only one that doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="BYD"
tp=`xinput list|grep "$name"|awk -F= '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'`
state=`xinput list-props $tp|grep 'Device Enabled'|awk -F\: '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'`
(( $state )) && xinput disable $tp || xinput enable $tp
```

BYD is the weird touchpad that came along with; substitute ALPS or Synaptics or the unique string from any other input device as needed/desired. It should work in any desktop environment as long as X is behind it.

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and write "gedit toggle_touchpad.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
condition="$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled)"

if [ "$condition" == "false" ]; then
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true
elif [ "$condition" == "true" ]; then
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
fi
```

Save the file and exit. Now you have a file with the name "toggle_touchpad.sh"

Run the command `chmod +x toggle_touchpad.sh` to make the file executable.

Place the file in any folder you like. Let us assume that you have it in the folder /home/username/myscripts/.

From the menu on the top-right go to `system-settings->keyboard->shortcuts->custom-shortcuts`.

Create a new shortcut and put as name whatever you want. Put as command `/home<username>;/myscripts/toggle_touchpad.sh` where "username" is your username

Assign whatever keyboard shortcut you want.

Ready :)

P.S. Personally I put the file in the `/opt/myscripts/` folder but in order to put it there you should run the following commands after creating the file:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/myscripts/

sudo mv toggle_touchpad.sh /opt/myscripts/

sudo chown <username>:<username> /opt/myscripts/toggle_touchpad.sh

chmod +x  /opt/myscripts/toggle_touchpad.sh
```

where "username" is your username

Then when you will create the shortcut you will use the path "/opt/myscripts/toggle_touchpad.sh" instead of the one mentioned above